# Is magnetic field inside a parallel plate capacitor same as outside due to cunduction current in wires.?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

[image]
For a circular parallel plate capacitor (when charging) with wires connected symmetrically, Is magnetic field at point M and N same? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point $N$ has a smaller distance $r$ from the axis than the radius $R$ of the parallel plate capacitor. Therefore the displacement current passing through the area on the circle defined by $r \lt R$ is not the total displacement current through the plate area with radius $R$. The conduction current in the wire has to be the same as the displacement current in the capacitor. Therefore the changing displacement current within the radius $r$ is smaller than the changing conduction current in the wire. Therefore the induced magnetic field at $r$ is smaller in the capacitor than at the wire.